# Post on Facebook Fan page through app

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

I've managed to create a class which posts on my facebook wall. But how do I change the code to share on my facebook fanpage instead? I can't find anything on google or stack overflow...

here is the class which shares on facebook:

```
package com.celticwolf.blahblah;  <--- changed

import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity{

    private static final String APP_ID = "35255389027859";  <--- changed
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

    private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
        private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return facebook.isSessionValid();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        restoreCredentials(facebook);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialog);

        String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
        if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
        }
        messageToPost = facebookMessage;
    }

    public void doNotShare(View button){
        finish();
    }
    public void share(View button){
        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            loginAndPostToWall();
        }
        else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }

    public void loginAndPostToWall(){
         facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message){ 
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(message);
    } 




class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
public Boolean doInBackground(String ...message){

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message[0]);
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
                facebook.request("me");   
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");  <---  I think here is the crucial part
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
        else {
             return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
} 

public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(result == Boolean.TRUE){
 showToast("posted successfully");
}else{
 showToast("couldn't post to FB.");
}
        finish();
}
}






    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

`me/feed` becomes `PAGE_ID/feed`:

```
String response = facebook.request("PAGE_ID/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Learn how to use the Graph API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I've addet the page Id like this:  String response = facebook.request("1187095234234/feed", parameters, "POST"); but it doesnt work...  do I have to integrate the page id differently? and do i need any other permissions ?

Comment: It Worked!! needet one of the permission  publish_actions manage_pages  publish_stream

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = facebook.request("PAGE_ID/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

This will be work but for posting in a Page you must need access token with Mangage_Pages and Publish_stream permissions.